# How to use cool-ascii-faces in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Just for fun, I'd like to use the javascript library [cool-ascii-faces](https://github.com/maxogden/cool-ascii-faces) in my Angular application. I followed the instructions in the blog "[How to use external JavaScript Libraries in Angular 8](https://medium.com/@clintpitzak/how-to-use-external-javascript-libraries-in-angular-8-247baacbdccf)".

I did the following things:

1. installed cool-ascii-faces per npm in my Angular project under node_modules.
2. In angular.json, added these two scripts to both build and test section:

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/cli.js",
              "./node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/index.js"
            ]
```

My app.components.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var coolFace: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void{
    console.log(coolFace());
  }
}
```

But, in the console I only see: ReferenceError: coolFace is not defined. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I think they export `faces` https://github.com/maxogden/cool-ascii-faces/blob/c7c04b4c7ce2877bf663efdfac4dcc182b53fe4e/index.js#L281

maybe try using the variable `declare var faces: any;`
You could also try importing as needed at the top of your file, sort of like this: `import * as coolFace from 'cool-ascii-faces';
`

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Andres O. Serrano for his advice. I tried both approach, neither worked.

But I came up with another solution. Simply store all the ascii faces in a Json file under /asset. Then follow the instruction in the blog "[How to Read Local JSON file in Angular](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-local-json-files/)". It works like a charm. Thanks!